# SSR doesn't seem to work with conditional rendering with Store

Tags: sveltekit

/lib/store/store.js

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store'

export const store = writable({ show: true ))
```

/route/index.svelte

```
<script>
import { store } from '$lib/stores/store'
</script>

{#if $store.show}
  <div class="view">
   My conditional elements
  </div>
{/if}
```

SSR stops working with conditional rendering with store. Is this a supposed behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: do you have a link to the repo, I try your code and it is working. with both ssr:true and ssr:false, do you mean reading local store?

Comment: @MSH. Hi Thanks for the response! I am glad that I can talk about this with someone. Actually, have you checked it in the source code of your HTML, and see if it is rendered? The code provided works on the client side only, meaning that it doesn't generate any SSR, and makes it flicker. I just checked it out, and the same thing... I will provide the repo this weekend as I am away.

Comment: check the image (  [SSR : false](https://imgur.com/h4K5h0f) , [SSR : true](https://imgur.com/rOSZCKk) )